# API-PLATFORM: Return data by language

Tags: symfony, translation, api-platform.com

I am currently working on programming an API using Symfony 6.2 and API Platform frameworks and PHP 8.1.

I am currently looking for a way through which the data can be returned according to the language provided.

For example, I have data with the following information in the database, which is returned by the API:

```
{
name: "Real Madrid",
description: "Commonly referred to as Real Madrid, is a Spanish professional football club based in Madrid that currently plays in La Liga."
}
```

Is there a way in which I can return the same API in Arabic, for example?

```
{
name: "ريال مدريد",
description: "يشار إليه عادة باسم ريال مدريد ، وهو ناد إسباني لكرة القدم مقره في مدريد ويلعب حاليًا في الدوري الأسباني."
}
```

I searched on the Internet and in the API Platform documents without any benefit. I also prefer to use the .xlf files for translation if there are anyway.

Comment: Does you have try to use the doctrine translatable extension?https://symfony.com/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/current/index.html or https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can make use of Symfony's built-in internationalization features along with the Accept-Language header in API requests.

First, you'll need to enable and configure internationalization in your Symfony project. In the config/packages/translation.yaml file, add the following configuration:

```yaml
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
```

I'm not sure using translation files is what you need but as you mentioned you want to use XLIFF translation files, create then a messages.ar.xlf file in the translations folder for Arabic translations, and add your translations there:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="real_madrid_name">
                <source>Real Madrid</source>
                <target>ريال مدريد</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="real_madrid_description">
                <source>Commonly referred to as Real Madrid, is a Spanish professional football club based in Madrid that currently plays in La Liga.</source>
                <target>يشار إليه عادة باسم ريال مدريد ، وهو ناد إسباني لكرة القدم مقره في مدريد ويلعب حاليًا في الدوري الأسباني.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Now, to make use of these translations, you can inject the TranslatorInterface in your controller and use it to translate the data before returning it:

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

// ...

public function getRealMadridData(TranslatorInterface $translator): JsonResponse
{
    $data = [
        'name' => $translator->trans('real_madrid_name'),
        'description' => $translator->trans('real_madrid_description')
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

Finally, make sure to pass the 'Accept-Language' header with the desired language code in your API requests. For example:

```
GET /api/clubs HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: ar
```

With this configuration, Symfony will automatically use the appropriate translation file based on the 'Accept-Language' header provided in the request.

In the case you would use data in database, you could use [doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md) or [KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/docs/translatable.md).

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.